# windows notify icon c# change message without refresh

Tags: c#

How do I change the message displayed within the notify icon baloon tip without the baloon refreshing.

I want to show a countdown timer before the application carries out an event and I want to use the onclick to cancel the event when the user clicks it.

Thanks
Sp

Comment: Just create your own notify frame/form. There are many articles online explaining this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The only way it to show a new balloon.

An alternative is to use a custom component like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx. I'm not sure whether this one supports what you require, but I'm sure there are out there that do.